# How can I stop getting a 'product is undefined' Javascript error in Magento Product page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, prototypejs

I have a custom magento store and I though everything was ok but i am having JS errors only on the product pages, and only on IE8!

If you view this page in IE8: http://www.guitarfood.com/featured-products/lava-mini-coil-guitar-patch-lead-purple.html

You will get a lot of JS errors to do with Magento. I think this is because I am using a jQuery image gallery, and Magento uses prototype. (Even though i have the no conflict set up - and it works as I use a slider on the hoe page with no errors.) I removed this jQuery gallery plug in and the page worked fine. So i thought i would add a prototype based gallery plugin, but then i get a 'product is undefined' JS error in IE8?

Here is the other version: http://dev.guitarfood.com/featured-products/planet-waves-pw-vg-01-varigrip.html

Ideally i would like to keep the jQuery slider from the original URL.

Does anyone have any ideas - i'm all out, and it's driving me mad.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try this approach for no conflict instead of inline:

Take a look at: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/javascript_related/how_to_use_jquery_1.2.6_lastest_with_prototype#jquery

Comment: Thanks, I will try that - but i do like using the google CDN jQuery.